# ASP.NET WEB API, unwanted parameters in request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net web api. I have a method in UserController which receives POST-requests:
`void Post([FromBoby] UserInfo userInfo)`
I have a model `UserInfo` with fields: `Login, Name`.
I can post json: `{Login:"someLogin", Name:"someName"}` and it will successfully mapped to `userInfo` parameter.
I can also post json: `{Login:"someLogin", Name:"someName", UnwantedParameter:"someString"}` which will also ssuccessfully mapped to UserInfo parameter and `UnwantedParameter` will be ignored.
How to handle 'unwanted' parameters to throw response exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this question, I believe you are asking the same thing:

[POST object in .NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790280/post-object-in-net-webapi)

At the end of the day, they suggest setting the following property (typically in the Global.asax.cs)

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
```

Comment: There is a new problem. JSON: {Login:"someLogin",Name:"someName"} successfully maped. JSON: {login:"someLogin",name:"someName"} could not be mapped. This problem started after setting MissingMemberHandling.Error. So now works only upper case json-input :(

Comment: Maybe there is a way to receive both camelCase and PascalCase JSON input?

Comment: try this GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();